Can typescript infer a generic type without it being passed as a function argument?
The title is imperfect, but I'm having trouble reducing this confusion down to one sentence. Maybe part of my problem is that I don't really understand exactly what I'm trying to do!
I have an app where I'm trying to read in data from different social media platforms. I want to be able to define each platform as an object, that implements certain functions. That way, when I want to add a support for a new platform, I just need to go create an object that implements those functions for that platform.
This is a simplified version of what I'm using so far:
type socialMediaDataProcessor<FetchedData, TransformedData> = {
  fetchData: (resourceId: string) => FetchedData;
  transformData: (fetchedData: FetchedData) => TransformedData;
};

const fetchFacebookData = (resourceId: string) => [
  { clicks: 50, ad_id: "9837op4293", page_id: "oiuhiuheovwu" },
  { clicks: 100, ad_id: "i9087gqu3i4", page_id: "njhbguy789uhi" },
];
const transformFacebookData = (
  facebookData: { clicks: number; ad_id: string; page_id: string }[],
) => {
  // do something to the facebook data
};

const facebookDataProcessor = {
  fetchData: fetchFacebookData,
  transformData: transformFacebookData,
} satisfies socialMediaDataProcessor<
  ReturnType<typeof fetchFacebookData>,
  ReturnType<typeof transformFacebookData>
>;

So I have this definition of a platform object, which p much says

a platform must implement two functions: fetchData and transformData
transformData's only argument is the return type of fetchData.

This works kinda ok, but it seems kind of redundant to have to specify the generic types for FetchedData and TransformedData.
Is there a different way I could set this up that wouldn't require me explicitly provide the types to the generic type socialMediaDataProcessor?
(Btw in this specific example, I guess don't actually have to specify the TransformedData type, but in my actual code there's a handful of types, so I feel like this illustrates the issue better)
